# iOS - How to disable UITableView scrolling to top when cell is being selected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

The problem is my UITableView automatically scrolls to top when I touch/select any cell.
I have no idea what might be the problem.
Here is the structure of my UITableView:

```
UITableViewController
 -table header:
  -UIView
   -UIScrollView with paging enabled
   -UIPageControl
 -Prototype Cell:
  -UIView
   - 3 UITextLabels
```

**ADDED:**

here is my code to show detailed view when cell is pressed, I don't use `didSelectRowAtIndex`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowEventDetails"]) {

        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        EventDetailsViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailViewController.event = [listOfEvents.eventsList objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please post the code that comes in the didselectrow

Comment: Are you using a scroll view, Try to set scrollView.bounces = NO;

Comment: I use scrollView only in a table's header. Disabling scrolling didn't fix my problem. But your comment helped me to find the problem! See the answer below :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed that by disabling `pagingEnabled` property for `tableView`.
Can anyone explain how can paging effect on tableview scrolling to top ??

Comment: Weird, had the same issue. No idea why it behaves like that.